# Convert list containing tuple to string

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have a list containing tuples. I need to convert the entire list to a string for compression. This code worked fine in Python 2.7:

```
tt = '{}'.format(tt)
```

But in Python 2.6 I get the following error:

```
  hist = '{}'.format(hist)
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

The data in `tt` looks like `[(2, 3, 4), (34, 5, 7)...]`

Any workaround for this, apart from upgrading the Python version?

Comment: Why not just use `str(tt)`? `str.format()` is great for interpolating values into a *larger string*; for one-off string conversions, just use `str()`. For one-value formatting, using the `format()` function.

Comment: Serializing Python objects as raw strings is not really a good idea. [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) are designed specifically for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put an index in the replacement field:

```
tt = '{0}'.format(tt)
```

Or just use:

```
tt = str(tt)
```

which will also support versions of Python prior to the introduction of `str.format` in 2.6.

Demo:

```
>>> tt = [(2, 3, 4), (34, 5, 7)]
>>> "{0}".format(tt)
'[(2, 3, 4), (34, 5, 7)]'
>>> str(tt)
'[(2, 3, 4), (34, 5, 7)]'
```

Comment: In Python 2.6+, one can also use `tt = format(tt)`.